# Set BACK Button to RETURN to Previous Layout

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android Studio

I am building a program in Android Studio about GIRDVIEW IMAGE.
I have set 2 layout: 
- layout1: **activity_main.xml** to display Girdview images
- layout2: **solo_picture.xml** to display only one Pictuter  and 1 Back button to help return layout 1 when user clicks it
.I have MainActivity.java and MyImageAdapter.java (enclose code)
This is a problem: I can't return layout1 when I click the Back button.
Although, I used :

```
 //want to use-save state values
Bundle myOriginalMemoryBundle;
myOriginalMemoryBundle = savedInstanceState;
```

.....

// set GO BACK button to return to layout1 (GridView)

```
btnSoloBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSoloBack);
btnSoloBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // redraw the main screen showing the layout1
              onCreate(myOriginalMemoryBundle);
            }
        });
```

I can't know why myOriginalMemoryBundle = NULL when I debug.
After, my program is Stopped , I can't return layout1 to continue activity...
Help you, please..
Thank you so much <3
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        //GUI control bound to screen1 (holding GidView)
        GridView gridview;
        //GUI controls bound to screen2 (holding single ImageView)
        TextView txtSoloMsg;
        ImageView imgSoloPhoto;
        Button btnSoloBack;
        //in case you want to use-save state values
        Bundle myOriginalMemoryBundle;

        String[] items = {"Photo-1", "Photo-2", "Photo-3", "Photo-4", "Photo-5",
                "Photo-6", "Photo-7", "Photo-8", "Photo-9", "Photo-10", "Photo-11",
                "Photo-12", "Photo-13", "Photo-14", "Photo-15",};
        Integer[] thumbnails={R.drawable.pic01_small,R.drawable.pic02_small,R.drawable.pic03_small,
                R.drawable.pic04_small,R.drawable.pic05_small,R.drawable.pic06_small,
                R.drawable.pic07_small,R.drawable.pic08_small,R.drawable.pic09_small,
                R.drawable.pic11_small,R.drawable.pic11_small,R.drawable.pic12_small,
                R.drawable.pic13_small,R.drawable.pic14_small,R.drawable.pic15_small};
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            myOriginalMemoryBundle = savedInstanceState;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // setup GridView with its custom adapter and listener
            gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            gridview.setAdapter(new MyImageAdapter(this, thumbnails));
            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    showBigScreen(position);
                }
            });
        }//onCreate
        private void showBigScreen(int position) {
            // show the selected picture as a single frame in the second layout
            setContentView(R.layout.solo_picture);
            // plumbing – second layout
            txtSoloMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSoloMsg);
            imgSoloPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSoloPhoto);
            // set caption-and-large picture
            txtSoloMsg.setText(" Position= " + position + " " + items[position]);
            imgSoloPhoto.setImageResource( thumbnails[position] );
            // set GO BACK button to return to layout1 (GridView)
            btnSoloBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSoloBack);
            btnSoloBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // redraw the main screen showing the GridView
                  onCreate(myOriginalMemoryBundle);
                }
            });
        }// showBigScreen
    }//Activity
```

**MyImageAdapter.java**

```
public class MyImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context; // main activity’s context
    Integer[] smallImages; // thumbnail data set
    public MyImageAdapter(Context mainActivityContext,
                          Integer[] thumbnails) {
        context =mainActivityContext;
        smallImages = thumbnails;
    }
    // how many entries are there in the data set?
    public int getCount() {
        return smallImages.length;
    }
    // what is in a given 'position' in the data set?
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return smallImages[position];
    }
    // what is the ID of data item in given 'position‘?
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    // create a view for each thumbnail in the data set
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        // if possible, reuse (convertView) image already held in cache
        if (convertView == null) {
            // no previous version of thumbnail held in the scrapview holder
            // define entry in res/values/dimens.xml for grid height,width in dips
            // <dimen name="gridview_size">100dp</dimen>
            // setLayoutParams will do conversion to physical pixels
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            int gridsize = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.gridview_size);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(gridsize, gridsize));
            //imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));//NOT a good practice
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(smallImages[position]);
        imageView.setId(position);
        return imageView;
    }//getView

}//MyImageAdapter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining your second layout in the same activity, you can just define another activity for layout "R.layout.solo_picture".

Then just parse selected image data from activity1 to activity2.

Android will automatically restore your previous data when you press back from activity2 to activity1.

Sorry for my bad english. English is not my main language.

Parsing data between activities using Intent:

On activity1:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
intent1.putExtra("item", items[position]);
intent1.putExtra("thumbnail", thumbnails[position])
startActivity(intent1);
```

On activity2:

```
Intent intent    = getIntent();
String item      = intent.getIntExtra("item", "");
String thumbnail = intent.getStringExtra("thumbnail", 0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll notice. So, I still want to try perform with two layout ...

Answer (score 0):

Define another activity for the layout **solo_picture.xml**. Suppose you have two activities: MainActivity and Activity2, and two layouts: activity_main.xml and solo_picture.xml. Then, write following code in onCreate method.

**MainActivity.java**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button button = (Button) findViewById((R.id.btn1));
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**Activity2.java**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity2); // R.layout.solo_picture in your case
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Now you can return to first layout on clicking button 2 or press back button of hardware.

Make sure to edit your **AndroidManifest.xml** file. Add Activity2 in this file.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>
```

Comment: @NguyenThanhHuong Glad I could help. Please mark if this answer is useful.

Comment: Hi @NguyenThanhHuong if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52462784/10372900) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Thanks.

Comment: yes, This is useful. I just have actived on Stackoverflow , so I don't know about Clicking the check-mark. Please sympathy to me. And, I already have Clicked the check mark :)